# Dynamically generated page in Javascript based on page link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am looking to insert javascript objects from a JSON file to create a dynamically generated page based on a users link clicked, sort of like a wildcard page in a framework such as laravel or django.

For example there is a list of houses with a link to a dynamically generated page depending on which link the user clicks. lets say the user clicks on a house from a list of houses, they are then sent to a template page and the JSON file then populates the page and inserts the correct info into the title and other elements.

I have been looking into AJAX and HTML5 local storage. Is this possible or am I barking up the completely wrong tree?

Comment: This is very possible. Not sure what you would use local storage for though unless you want to save a post code or something along those lines so it only populates the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely possible, and how most pages work.  You do not need local storage, unless you want to actually load a new page, and want to store some information across pages.

As you want to do this through AJAX, you are most probably looking for a single page layout, where on click of the house you will first hide the current panel, show the new panel where the house data should go, and show a loader while the Ajax loads the info.  Once the Ajax call returns the data in Jason format, you can proceed to populate the panel with your template + JSON , and hide the loader.

If you plan to do this on page load, you can have some kind of identifier you append to the URL you are clicking on, and based on that make the Ajax call.  Thereafter populate the page with template + JSON